# how do I change the default admin_user/pass for activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I know this is a pretty simple question but I can't figure out where to change the login/pass that active admin gives you upon initial installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in `lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb`. If you've already run these, then look in `db/migrate/` for the `devise` migration. The default of "password" should be in there.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, i'm a noob to activeadmin/devise. I don't have that file in my app...should I? How do I run the generator to make a new admin and remove the default one? also, i dont think i have devise installed... thank you

Comment: Which steps in "Getting Started" have you completed? https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin

Comment: I have installed the gem, installed activeadmin, created 2 models. But now I realize I don't know how to change the default admin user. I never installed devise since it wasn't on the getting started list.

Comment: These docs might be better for you in that case.  http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html#running_the_generator

Comment: I don't see anything there that would help me...I am confused. I have completed all of those steps already.

Comment: I just ran `rails generate active_admin:install` on a clean Rails 3 app, with the appropriate gems added from those docs. It created a Devise migration with the default user/pass. Did you maybe forget to run `bundle:install` or something?

Comment: You actually did install devise.. You just didn't realize it. It's part of active_admin.

Answer (score 2):

do a search of your migration directory for this.

```
AdminUser.create!(:email =>
```

It will have the default username and password.

PS.. Programmers notepad is a great windows tool for editing ruby.  No I don't have stock in it. :)